# Select maximum of 2 columns

Tags: soql

Is it possible to take the maximum of 2 columns as a new column?

Something like:

```
select max(start_date, end_date) from contract
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This is valid in SQL, but not SOQL. You can take the individual max of each field, but you must compare those values on the client.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a formula field on the Contract that would return the max of the two dates, then use that in your report.

```
IF(start_date>end_date, start_date, end_date)
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks neat, but unfortunately not possible in my scenario.